# I have disabled PHP Error reporting in php.ini but it continues to show in browser

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

So I have disabled PHP Errors inside my `php.ini` file (`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`) but they still continue to show in browser. I am running PHP version `5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13` and to do this I used the following:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING

display_errors = Off

display_startup_errors = Off
```

Examples of errors still showing include:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value ...

and

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in ...

Any help/advice as to why these errors may still be showing would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe sudo service apache2 restart?

Comment: Do not use deprecated functions! fix this with MYSQLi or PDO. Hide the errors it's not a good solution.

Comment: Try restarting apache. The following line will work if included in all scripts. No restart required. `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Comment: I have restarted apache2 a few times; but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.
I created a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` file, and even it is saying that `error_reporting` is off in both the local and master value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured this out, with the help of Ukavi in the comments.

The errors started to display after I had transferred the site from one server to another, and it appears that the first server ran an older version of PHP which is why they did not show up before.

Anyway, the fix. I added this to wp-config.php:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
```

I also did a find in files for `ini_set` and found a few instances where they had been deliberately activated. As this site is not a solo project I wasn't aware of this!

Thank you for all the advice guys.